# Python Selenium find element from specific div

Tags: python, selenium

[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://ggl-maxim.com/')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="body"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/fieldset/input[1]').send_keys('tnrud3080')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="body"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/fieldset/input[2]').send_keys('tnrud3080')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="body"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/fieldset/button[1]').click()

time.sleep(2)
driver.get('https://ggl-maxim.com/api/popup/popup_menu.asp?mobile=0&lobby=EVOLUTION')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("gameIframe"))
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".svg--1nrnH")))
targets = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".svg--1nrnH")
res = []
for el in targets:
    res.append(el.get_attribute('innerHTML'))

print(*res, sep='\n')
```

This code gets the svg (records of the game) as you look at the picture. However, if you click the button that I wrote "multi" the picture at the bottom, I can see records also at the right of the page. I found out that this part shows up the records more faster than before. In order to do that I have to get svg value only from that div. How can I? Please help me!

[image]

Comment: Check the answer. I do not recommend this way of solving the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second approach is not faster and is harder to implement, as each container is loaded separately and starts to reload after the first load is done. It looks like a nightmare to automate.

I tried Selenium's explicit waits and time.sleep() neither of the approached worked.
The code below clicks the button, switches to a new iframe and tries to get containers content. But the content is almost always empty for the reasons described above.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver')
driver.get('http://ggl-maxim.com/')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="body"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/fieldset/input[1]').send_keys('tnrud3080')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="body"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/fieldset/input[2]').send_keys('tnrud3080')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="body"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/fieldset/button[1]').click()

time.sleep(2)
driver.get('http://ggl-maxim.com/api/popup/popup_menu.asp?mobile=0&lobby=EVOLUTION')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("gameIframe"))
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".svg--1nrnH")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[data-role=button-label]"))).click()

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".sidebar-container>iframe")))
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".sidebar-container")))
iframe2 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('iframe[src^="https://evo.kplaycasino.com/frontend/evo/r2/"]')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe2)
# wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".list--BLuiJ .svg--1nrnH")))
time.sleep(20)
targets = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".list--BLuiJ .svg--1nrnH")
res = []
for el in targets:
    res.append(el.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
print(*res, sep='\n')
```

As you see, even 20 seconds is not enough, because content is reloading on fly.

I left explicit wait commented, so you could reassure that it won't work as well.

However, from my answer you can learn how to find a locator which starts with a specific text:

```
iframe2 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('iframe[src^="https://evo.kplaycasino.com/frontend/evo/r2/"]')
```

Where, `src^=`means that src starts with some specified text.